Does convergence in total variation imply weak convergence $\mu_j \stackrel{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$?
We'd like to show that if $|\mu_j-\mu|(A) \to 0$ for every bounded open set $A\subset\Bbb R^n$, then $\mu_j \stackrel{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$, i.e., for every $\phi\in C_c(\Bbb R^n)$, we have $\lim_{j\to\infty} \int \phi\, d\mu_j = \int \phi\, d\mu$.

We will only consider non-negative measures. If $\mu,\nu$ are two measures, the total variation of $\mu -\nu$ on an open set $A$ is defined as
$$|\mu-\nu|(A) := \sup_{\phi\in C_c(A)\\|\phi|\le 1}\int \phi(x) d (\mu-\nu)(x).$$
Let $\{\mu_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be locally finite non-negative measures on $\Bbb R^n$.
To show the result, consider the difference $$\left|\int \phi\, d\mu_j - \int\phi\, d\mu \right| = \left|\int\phi\, d(\mu_j-\mu)\right|,$$
where $\phi\in C_c(\Bbb R^n)$. As $\phi$ is compactly supported, we can find an open set $A$ containing $\operatorname{supp}\phi$. We can assume $|\phi|\le 1$ by scaling since $\phi$ is bounded. Ideally, one would upper-bound the integral over $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ with the integral over $A$, and use convergence in total variation to conclude. However, the difference measure $\mu_j-\mu$ is not necessarily non-negative, so these arguments may fail. How should I show weak convergence? Thanks!

It seems for me that you already have the required implication. Indeed, we picked an open set $A$ containing $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ and assumed $|\phi|\le 1$. We have $|\mu_j-\mu|(A) \to 0$, so it seems $\int \phi(x) d (\mu_j-\mu)(x)\to 0$ and thus $\int \phi, d\mu_j - \int\phi, d\mu\to 0$

@AlexRavsky Does it not matter that $\mu_j - \mu$ is not necessarily non-negative?

As far as I see, it does not matter, because we are given that $\left|\int \phi(x) d (\mu_j-\mu)(x)\right|=\left|\int \phi, d\mu_j - \int\phi, d\mu\right|$ and
$$|\mu_j-\mu|(A)=\sup_{\phi\in C_c(A)\|\phi|\le 1}\int \phi(x) d (\mu_j-\mu)(x)$$ tends to $0$ when $j$ tends to the infinity.

You want to prove that :
$$\sup_{\phi \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n), |\phi| \leq 1} \int \phi ~ d(\mu-\mu_j) \underset{j \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$
implies
\begin{equation} \forall \phi \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n), \quad \int \phi ~ d(\mu-\mu_j) \underset{j \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 \label{equ-a-montrer} \end{equation}
As you noted, you can restrict your attention to $\phi \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $|\phi| \leq 1$ up to rescaling.
Now note that up to replacing $\phi$ by $-\phi$, you also have
$$ \inf_{\phi \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n), |\phi| \leq 1} \int \phi ~ d(\mu-\mu_j) \underset{j \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$
since the $-\inf$ and the $\sup$ have to agree.
This implies the desired result.
You can actually prove in full generality the stronger statement by a similar method :
$$ \left| \int \phi ~ d\mu \right| \leq \int |\phi| ~ d|\mu| $$
(which also directly imply what you want).
